# How can I randomize the order of two sets of elements in jquery/javascript, so that they remain in sync with each order?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following mark up:

```
<div id="elements1">
    <div>Item 1</div>
    <div>Item 2</div>
    <div>Item 3</div>
    <div>Item 4</div>
    <div>Item 5</div>
</div>
<br/>
<ul id="elements2">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

I want to generate a random order that both of these lists would use. So a desired output could look like:

```
<div id="elements1">
    <div>Item 2</div>
    <div>Item 5</div>
    <div>Item 3</div>
    <div>Item 1</div>
    <div>Item 4</div>
</div>
<br/>
<ul id="elements2">
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

`#elements1` will always have the same number of children in it as `#elements2` and visa versa.

My pseudo code looks like like:

```
// see how many child elements in #elements1
// create order array based on # of child elements in i.e. [1,2,3,4,5]
// randomize array
// use order array to reorder both #elements1 and #elements2
// .appendTo() respective parents
```

Does my strategy seem like it would be efficient for the task at hand? (I will produce working code in a minute.) If not, what would be a better way to go about this? Thanks for your help!

Edit: Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/H4Crr/) to mess around with.

Comment: Your pseudo code looks sound. You should try writing some real code and see what happens. It'll be easier to help you if you have more specific questions.

Comment: I think I was getting hung up on if my strategy is the most practical/efficient or if I should consider a different approach. I'll code it out to get something working, and see if anyone can suggest any other improved strategies. Thanks!

Comment: With arrays of size like 5 elements, you can basically do pretty much anything to it without worrying whether it's optimal - you'd essentially have to screw up pretty badly to make some method on a small set of elements become significantly larger than O(n) :P  Your pseudocode is what I was going to suggest.  Look at your data set to see if you have a significant amount of elements in your lists and test your code with that if you're still worried :D

Comment: I know how that can be. It's easy to get hung up on trying to find an 'optimal' solution. You pretty much shouldn't worry about optimization until you find that you have a performance problem. EDIT: also, what euxneks said.

Comment: If the items in the 2 lists are related, then they could be paired up as objects which look something like Thing {Id, Element1, Element2}. Then you could maintain an array of those and reorder them as you like, and you'd never lose the pairings. However you would probably have to trash and rebuild html for UL content after every re-order.

Comment: Also, if you do have a significant number of elements then you'll probably want to use a [document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createDocumentFragment) for appending to.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I guess I might've meant I was looking for the most elegant way to do this, rather than the most "efficient" (performance-wise) solution. Thanks!

Comment: While others have coded out my pseudo code pretty much exactly as I described it, @louisbros's answer was a more concise approach than mine. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way would be to use a [documentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DocumentFragment) for this:

```
// lists with equal length
var list1 = document.getElementById('elements1');
var list2 = document.getElementById('elements2');
// a place to stash the items while randomizing
var stash1 = document.createDocumentFragment();
var stash2 = document.createDocumentFragment();

// initial length
var length = list1.childNodes.length;

// choose the same random child from the lists
// put them in their stashes preserving the new order
while(length > 0){
    var random = Math.floor((Math.random()*--length));
    stash1.appendChild(list1.childNodes[random]);
    stash2.appendChild(list2.childNodes[random]);
}

// put the elements back in the lists when done
list1.appendChild(stash1);
list2.appendChild(stash2);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/louisbros/NPPpt/

Comment: I do like this approach because of how short the code is. And the browser support fits my needs. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I think the `documentFragment` is pretty well suited to what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the the second array of selected elements using an array of values that has sorted the first collection.

```
// selecting elements
var $elem1 = $('#elements1 div'),
    $elem2 = $('#elements2 li');

// cloning elements (for reordering)
var $ordered1 = $elem1.clone(),
    $ordered2 = $elem2.clone();

// randomizing elements
var helper = [],
    i = -1,
    $randomized1 = $elem1.sort(function () {
        var n = 0.5 - Math.random();
        helper.push(n);
        return n;
    }),
    $randomized2 = $elem2.sort(function () {
        return helper[++i];
    });

// .appendTo() respective parents
$('#elements1').append($randomized1);
$('#elements2').append($randomized2);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zGLZG/

Answer (score 1):

To simply randomise the order of an [*Array*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), you could do something like this

```
function shuffleArray(a) { // Fisher-Yates shuffle
    var i = a.length, t, j;
    while (--i) { // loop over each item in array (except 0 because no point)
        j = (Math.random() * (i+1)) | 0; // random Int j <= i
        t = a[i], a[i] = a[j], a[j] = t; // swap items i and j
    }
}
```

You'll need to convert your [*HTMLCollection*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/HTMLCollection) to something non-live so you can use it more easily, for example use

```
elements1 = document.getElementById('elements1'); // cache for later
nodes1 = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements1.children); // children to Array

elements2 = document.getElementById('elements2');
nodes2 = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements2.children);
```

Now for the thing you actually want to randomise (if you don't want to modify the function above to shuffle two arrays at the same time, see below)

```
i = nodes1.length, a = new Array(i);
while (i--) a[i] = i;
// a = [0, 1, 2, 3, ...]
```

Now simply randomise `a`, and re-append the nodes following the new order of numbers

```
shuffleArray(a); // a = e.g. [4, 8, 2, 5, ...]
for (i = 0; i < nodes1.length; ++i) {
    elements1.appendChild(nodes1[a[i]]); // append in new order
    elements2.appendChild(nodes2[a[i]]);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/H4Crr/3/). I've ignored `var` but remember to use it as applicable.

---

Decided to add a modified version of the shuffle for 2 *Arrays*, as this will most likely be much faster.

```
function shuffleTwoArrays(a, b) { // Shuffle 2 arrays same length in same way
    var i = a.length, t, j;
    while (--i) { // loop over each item in array (except 0 because no point)
        j = (Math.random() * (i+1)) | 0; // random Int j <= i
        t = a[i], a[i] = a[j], a[j] = t; // swap items i and j in a
        t = b[i], b[i] = b[j], b[j] = t; // swap items i and j in b
    }
}
```

Here you would just do

```
shuffleTwoArrays(nodes1, nodes2); // shuffle both the same
for (i = 0; i < nodes1.length; ++i) {
    elements1.appendChild(nodes1[i]); // re-append to achieve new order
    elements2.appendChild(nodes2[i]);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/H4Crr/4/).